# MySQL: how to change the data location

Tags: mysql

I use MySQL 5.2.36 CE. When I installed it, the software was installed to

```
C:\Program Files (X86)\MySQL
```

The database location was given to

```
D:\ABC\MySQL
```

I am hoping to change the database location to

```
D:\DEF\MySQL
```

Any quick way do it? I use a Windows 7 pro 64-bit machine.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1):

Shutdown mysql, move the data directory to the new location, open my.cnf and change the value of "datadir" to the new path.

Comment: and don't forget to restart mysql

Comment: Thanks for help! Cannot find my.cnf file in Windows 7.